# Cake Build set full version with DotNetCoreBuild alias

Tags: c#, coreclr, cakebuild

I'm using the `ParseReleaseNotes` alias in Cake to manage my versioning, worked fine with a project where I patch the assembly info with `CreateAssemblyInfo` alias.

Now with project not using csproj but project.json I want to achieve the same and assembly info isn't an real option with project.json.

Checking out the `DotNetCoreBuild(string, ​DotNetCoreBuildSettings)​` and it's `DotNetCoreBuildSettings` there only seems to be a way to set parts of the version via it's `VersionSuffix` property.

Is there an Cake alias / setting to achieve this or is it possible to patch the project.json from Cake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in alias to patch `project.json` version or parameter for `dotnet build` to set full version that I know of.

That said as `project.json` is just "JSON" it's fully possible to patch `project.json` using a JSON serializer i.e. `JSON.Net`.

Below I've created an example that references `JSON.Net` as an addin and then created an `UpdateProjectJsonVersion` utility function that I can use to patch my `project.json` using parsed the [ReleaseNotes](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common/0fd0c329) (in this case I've hard coded it for simplicity).

```
#addin "Newtonsoft.Json"

// fake a release note
ReleaseNotes releaseNotes = new ReleaseNotes(
    new Version("3.0.0"),
    new [] {"3rd release"},
    "3.0.-beta"
    );

// project.json to patch
FilePath filePaths = File("./project.json");

// patch project.json
UpdateProjectJsonVersion(releaseNotes.RawVersionLine, filePaths);

// utility function that patches project.json using json.net
public static void UpdateProjectJsonVersion(string version, FilePath projectPath)
{
    var project = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(
        System.IO.File.ReadAllText(projectPath.FullPath, Encoding.UTF8));

    project["version"].Replace(version);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(projectPath.FullPath, project.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

So basically just call `UpdateProjectJsonVersion` before you call the [DotNetCoreBuild](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.dotnetcore/df2c8647/fe14d930) alias and it'll result in same version as your release notes.

Answer (score 5):

There is no built in Cake Alias to provide this functionality, but you can make use of a 3rd Party Addin for the [MagicChunks](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/magic-chunks) project.  You can add this into your Cake script by simply doing:

`#addin "MagicChunks"`

And from there, you can do something like:

```
var projectToPackagePackageJson = $"{projectToPackage}/project.json";
Information("Updating {0} version -> {1}", projectToPackagePackageJson, nugetVersion);

TransformConfig(projectToPackagePackageJson, projectToPackagePackageJson, new TransformationCollection {
    { "version", nugetVersion }
});
```

Where TransformConfig is the Method Alias that is added by the MagicChunks addin.

**NOTE:** This sample was taken from the following [project](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/CSProjToXProj/blob/master/build.cake#L110).